# I cannot open my Jupyter Notebook, it keeps crashing on memory

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

As stated in the title I have a jupyter notebook that won't open.
I just start with programming and so it might be something silly.

I get an error message that says states: "Out of memory".
I cannot clear the output or shut down the kernel since it just won't open.
The used this Jupyter Notebook for work, where it opens some a very large excel document which is 100mb.
When I look into the directory I see that the Jupyter Notebook itself is 200mb.
I know Excel files shouldn't be that large but I am forced to work with them for work.
I already did quite some work in this Jupyter Notebook, is there a way to atleast save the code that I wrote?

Comment: Try to open the `.ipynb` file with a text editor like Notepad++, Editor or TextEdit. Then search for `"cells": [`. There should be the code for each cell in Jupyter Notebook. You can copy paste your code than.

Comment: Thanks Gandhi, nice name btw. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You're welcome :) But don't know about the out of memory part...

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

Source: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/2023/02/my-jupyter-notebook-crashed-and-now-wont-open/

```py
from nbformat import read, write

def Remove_Output(Book):

    for cell in Book.cells:

        if hasattr(cell, "outputs"):

            cell.outputs = []

        if hasattr(cell, "prompt_number"):

            del cell["prompt_number"]

Book= read(open("Old_notebook.ipynb"), 4)
Remove_Output(Book)
write(Book, open("New_notebook.ipynb", "w"), 4)
```